# Interesting relationship between cardinality and Lebesgue outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

If two sets $A$ and $B$ defined on bounded intervals have the same cardinality and $ A \bigcap B $ is non empty and the Lebesgue outer measure of A is greater than zero. Is it then true that the Lebesgue outer measure of B is also greater than zero.

Comment: Do you have thoughts on it yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cantor set has measure $0$ and has the same cardinality as $[0,1]$, which has measure $1$.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @stalker2133: Zachary's answer is correct; you should consider accepting it (press the checkmark beside their answer).

Comment: @ Zachary please could you answer the edited question?

Comment: @stalker2133 If you have a separate question, ask it as a separate question. Don't gradually trickle in additional information. Besides my counterexample works for that too.

Comment: @stalker2133: Letting $C$ denote the Cantor set, $C\cap [0,1]=C\neq \emptyset$